# How to retrieve global value set values assigned to Task recordtype through metadata API

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, tasks, activities

How do I, through the metadata, retrieve the picklistvalues assigned to a task recordtype, when the picklist is a global value set?

I've tried with the following package.xml, however neither the activity or task file contains any recordtype specific value set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Call_and_Meeting_Result</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Activity.Call_Result__c</members>
        <members>Task.Call_Result__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Task.Follow_Up_Task</members>
        <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

Hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A little late with a half-answer.  I was not able to retrieve...however I am able to deploy.  I manually put the xml in the RecordType metadata file and did a fource:source:deploy of the RecordType, and the changes were deployed properly.  Hope this helps.